# Stellaris TCP/IP

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, communication, stellaris

I have Stellaris LM3S6965 Microcontroller from TI, and i want to run an embedded web server on it. Is it possible to achieve that without additional hardware(ethernet/serial).

Thank you.

Comment: Being a microcontroller, it will necessarily need additional hardware: Figure 15.4 in the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3s6965.pdf will show you an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the LM3S6965 integrates both the Ethernet MAC and PHY; but will still require the ethernet isolation transformer (and RJ45 jack unless you solder the cat 5 right to the board).